# How to prove $\sum\nolimits_{k = 0}^\infty {{b_k}/{{(z - {z_0})}^k}} $ is uniformly convergence for all z in that annulus

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I read this in my book

> By substituting the reciprocal of $\left( {z{\rm{ }} - {\rm{ }}{z_0}} \right)$in the power series, we can show
> that if $\sum\nolimits_{k = 0}^\infty  {{b_k}/{{(z - {z_0})}^k}} $
> is convergent in the annulus ${r_2} < |z - {z_0}| < {r_1}$, then
> it is uniformly convergent for all z in that annulus, and the series represents
> a continuous function of z there

I have tried to use the definition of uniform convergence to prove it. However ,I find it's hard for me to even understand it . Why does uniformly convergence follows from convergence in some area ?(I know maybe I should write more about my effort to solve it ,but I just have no idea about how to do it )
Thanks!!!